# A Kendo Template with DropDownList inside form layout generates invald template when setting ServerFiltering to True

Tags: asp.net-core, kendo-ui, telerik

When creating kendo ui Javascript template and using a form layout, adding a DropDownList with server filtering set to true, kendo ui will throw an "invalid template" error.

While setting the server filtering to false it will work as expected.

Sample code

https://github.com/Elrashid/TelerikAspNetCoreApp.tiket.2022121901

Compiled code

https://github.com/Elrashid/TelerikAspNetCoreApp.tiket.2022121901/releases/download/202211219194020/publish-self-contaned.zip

Tested Scenarios:

- DropDownList with ServerFiltering true inside Kendo template will work
- DropDownList with ServerFiltering false will was a Form Layout editor inside Kendo template will work
- DropDownList with ServerFiltering true will was a Form Layout editor inside Kendo template will **not** work

Error :

[[image]](https://i.stac> k.imgur.com/nULHE.png)

Error code :

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="dropDownList_inside_form_ServerFiltering_true_template">

    @(Html.Kendo().Form<TelerikAspNetCoreApp.tiket._2022121901.Controllers.Biblio>()
                .Name("Biblio_Form")
                .HtmlAttributes(new { action = "Biblio_Save", method = "POST", })
                .Layout("grid")
                .Grid(g => g.Cols(1).Gutter(10))
                .Validatable(v =>
                    {
                        v.ValidateOnBlur(true);
                        v.ValidationSummary(vs => vs.Enable(false));
                    })
                .Items(items =>
                {
                    items.Add()
                         .Field(f => f.BiblioId)
                         .Label(l => l.Text("Biblio Id"))
                         .Editor(e =>
                            {
                                e.DropDownList()
                                    .HtmlAttributes(new { })
                                    .DataTextField("Title")
                                    .DataValueField("BiblioId")
                                    .NoDataTemplate("nodata")
                                    .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
                                    .DataSource(source =>
                                            {
                                                source.Read(read =>
                                                {
                                                    read.Action("biblio_read", "Home");
                                                })
                                        .ServerFiltering(true);
                                            });
                            });
                }).ToClientTemplate())
</script>
```

Comment: I would suggest trying to get just the template output for both the functioning version with ServerFiltering=false and the error version with ServerFilter=true, and use a text comparison tool to isolate the differences and see if you're missing an escape character or something similar (this is usually what I run into when hitting an invalid template error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Explicitly call the .ToClientTemplate() configuration method.
- Addunique identifier thru .Name() configuration option.
- this will have to be doen even if you call.ToClientTemplate() on the parent , so you have to call it for the children also

  ```
   <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="...........">

   @(Html.Kendo().Form<Biblio>()
   .Name("Biblio_Form")
   ....
   .Items(items =>
   {
       items.Add()
       .Field(f => f.BiblioId)
       .Label(l => l.Text("Biblio Id"))
       .Editor(e =>
       {
           e.DropDownList()
           .Name("serverFilteringTrue")
           .DataTextField("Title")
           .DataValueField("BiblioId")
           .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
           .DataSource(source =>
               {
                   source.Read(read =>
                   {
                       read.Action("biblio_read", "Home");
                   })
           .ServerFiltering(true);
               }).ToClientTemplate();
       });

   }).ToClientTemplate())
   </script>
  ```

Ref.

[ASP.NET Core Data Grid Component Client Detail Templates - Telerik UI for ASP.NET Core]
(https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-core/html-helpers/data-management/grid/templates/client-detail-template)